# My app crashes when I Log in because of Badge Counter(getOrCreateBadge) for Kotlinn

Tags: android, kotlin, authentication, notifications

Kotlin issue
If I am already logged into the app, the badge counter works, but if I log out and try to log back in I get this error.
Any advice on how to fix this issue?

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo
Caused by: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException

class MainActivity (): AppCompatActivity() {

```
var post: List<Post>? = null
private var notificationList: List<Notification>? = null
private var notificationAdapter: NotificationAdapter? = null


private val onNavigationItemSelectedListener =
            BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->

        when (item.itemId) {

            R.id.nav_home -> {
                badgeCounter()
                moveToFragment(SearchFragment())
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true

            }
            R.id.nav_search -> {
                badgeCounter()
                moveToFragment(HomeFragment())
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true


            }
            R.id.nav_add -> {
                badgeCounter()
                moveToFragment(PostSelectionFragment())
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true

            }
            R.id.nav_notifications -> {
                    badgeCounter()
                    if (moveToFragment(NotificationsFragment()) != null) {
                        badgeClear()

                    }else{
                    }
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true

            }
            R.id.nav_profile -> {
                badgeCounter()
                moveToFragment(ProfileFragment())
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true

                              }


        }

        false

    }

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav_view)

    navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(onNavigationItemSelectedListener)

   moveToFragment(SearchFragment())
    badgeCounter()


}





private fun moveToFragment(fragment: Fragment) {

    val fragmentTrans = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    fragmentTrans.replace(R.id.framelayout_Container, fragment)
    fragmentTrans.commit()


}


private fun badgeClear() {
    val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav_view)


    val badgeDrawable = navView.getOrCreateBadge(R.id.nav_notifications)
    if (badgeDrawable != null) {
        badgeDrawable.isVisible = false
        badgeDrawable.clearNumber()


    }


}

 fun badgeCounter(){
    val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav_view)
    val currentUserID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid

    val badgeDrawable = navView.getOrCreateBadge(R.id.nav_notifications).apply {
        val notiRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Notifications")
            .child(currentUserID)

        notiRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                if (p0.exists()) {
                    number = p0.childrenCount.toInt()
                    isVisible = true
                }else{
                    isVisible = false
                }
            }
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

        })
    }
    }
```

}

Comment: KotlinNullPointerException means you misused `!!`. You really shouldn’t ever have a need to use `!!`. Don’t use it if you don’t understand what it’s doing.

Comment: I am new to coding and self-taught. Could you give me a hand with this, by giving some more details?

Comment: The Kotlin documentation gives a very clear overview of what nulls and null-safety is here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html After you read that: basically what you're doing is declaring that Firebase's `currentUser` can never be null when you use `!!` on it. But the fact that it's nullable in the first place as declared by Firebase tells you that is not a safe assumption. You have to deal with the possibility that there is no current user, that it might be null.

Comment: You can see in the Firebase documentation, that `currentUser` will be null when the user is not signed in, so this is an expected state you must handle. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#kotlin+ktx

Comment: Thank you Tenfour04 for the information, unfortunately, I am still not able to figure this out. Would you mind making the adjustments in my code?